# Accessing Lambda functionality in Amazon Lex console

Tags: amazon-lex

I started playing around with Amazon Lex to build chatbots. I've been following their examples but one issue is that I can't see to use the Lambda functionality in the user console. I can't tell if this is due to the resource 404s I see in the console or if this functionality cannot be controlled through the UI.

I'm not able to type into the AWS Lambda function field under Fulfillment on an intent, but I can't figure out where to populate what goes in that dropdown. The page does have some 404s, specifically around loading the /lex/api/iam resource.

Is anyone familiar with the Lex console? I've looked through the documentation, I've disabled all browser extensions that might be interfering, I feel like I'm missing something but don't know what. Thanks for reading if you got this far.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The list is populated by your [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/details/) functions in the same region. You must have already created a Lambda function for this list to be populated.

AWS Lambda also requires access permission for Lex as below:

`aws lambda add-permission --function-name lex-test --statement-id chatbot-fulfillment --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --principal "lex.amazonaws.com"`

Answer (score 0):

These are the lambda functions which you made for your lex bots.
If you have created lambda function already, you need to refresh the browser in order to see it in drop-down. Both lex and lambda must be in same region. Also, you need to provide access permissions to your lambda function for lex.